# Buzzing Bill's Newspaper: Four Letter Splits

Tags: code-golf

"Buzzing" Bill is a well respected beaver. He is the hardest working in his home dam. He was a strong beaver and was able to lift more logs than anyone at the dam. Unfortunately Buzzing Bill's career came to an end in a tragic accident. Being such a prominent figure in  his town, the Beaver newspaper wanted to write a frontpage story remembering Buzzing Bill. However Beavers have much smaller newspapers than we do and can only fit 4 letters on each line. The newspaper is assigning you to the task of writing some code to output the four letter lines.

**The objective:**
We need some code written that takes in a string as an input, ex: *"Big Beaver Buzzing Bill Bite the Bullet"* and splits it into four letter segments that can fit on the Beaver newspaper, and outputs the split segments in an array/list/structure

The answer to this question will have an output to the sentence above that looks much like this:
**[Big,Bea,ver,Buz,zing,Bill,Bite,the,Bul,let]**

The output will complete the all of these criterion for beaver readability:

1. Keeps **4 letter words or less together, and completely separate from other words**, two words cannot occupy the same line— note that the first two indexes is not [BigB,eav]
2. It **splits words more than four letters and an even number of letters cleanly in two** — i.e. do not have [Beav,er]
3. **Words with an 7 letters should split at the point between the *first* two identical adjacent consonants, where one consonant occupies the middle spot, if possible.** “y” is not a consonant — Buzzing:[Buz,zing] instead of [Buzz,ing], additionally in very rare cases where the there is a triple consonant in the center, ex: “Wallled” would become [Wal,lled] as the split occurs at the first middle pair
4. **Words with an odd number of letters that do not satisfy rule #3 should be split so that the front of the word contains the extra letter** — "Beavers" should be split as [Beav, ers] rather than [Bea,vers]
5. Beavers are not very good at reading, so the **newspaper will not use any words over 8 letters, and all words will be entirely lowercase letters(only the 26 used in English)**

Make the Best of it Busy Beavers!

Comment: @KidWithComputer There's no rule establishing that two words can't share a line. If that's your intention, you might want to add one.

Comment: And to clarify rule 3, is `breeder` to be split `bree, der`, since the doubled pair is of a vowel?

Comment: how shall we split `wallled` (to be led by a wall)?

Comment: @UnrelatedString I edited the question accordingly to make it explicitly clear, and you are correct for the split of breeder

Comment: @Adám I edited many of the rules to accordingly, thank you, to clarify additionally, sayyids would become [sayy, ids], hypens will not be given as an input

Comment: Note that your example is not consistent anymore with the 5th rule (lowercase only).

Comment: @Arnauld you are correct but I’m keeping it so that beginnings of words are easier to see in the examples, I think it helps visually in the prompt

Comment: Nice story! :-)

Comment: @KjetilS Thank you!!! I worked hard on it :-)

Comment: Regarding the third rule, should `bbbbabc` split into `b,bbbabc` (first two identical adjacent consonants, where one of the `b`s is in the middle spot) or `bbb,babc` (same, but where it's split before the middle `b`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen by the middle spot I meant one of the b’s in the split must occupy the middle of the word, the fourth letter, your second interpretation is correct

Comment: Hey I'm new to this, when am I supposed to mark a winner?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
Ḳµ3.ịfƒØYL×7=LạLH>2×ƊĊṬk)Ẏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYsxDsIwEAS/ci0NBRRUUFP4Aylt@QiGI5HiI8j5AFKQKGhCS0@FhAShwyj/8EuMm5V2ZneDRC7G8Hp8n9Nx@JxWw8VfM@G72VyE/iaWi4nvhvbXhvd9Owr9OfpjFqMyOSiUNVag9k1jilQNUQpG4DUmSoQMeWWwRg3KgYSDpAQ16DKtK0Sd3rLQYMsdQlGyVIRgORkmB1Y6Z7QFaS3yHw)

This... can probably still be better...

```
Ḳµ                      )     For each word:
      ƒ                       Reduce
  3.ị                         the third and fourth letters in the word
     f                        by intersection
       ØY                     starting with the list of all consonants.
         L                    Is the length of that result
          ×7                  times 7
            =L                equal to the length of the word?
              ạL              Decrement the length if so.
                H             Halve,
                 >2×Ɗ         zero if =< 2,
                     Ċ        ceil,
                      Ṭk      split after that index.
                         Ẏ    Flatten the splits together.
```

Comment: Awesome work so far, however Asset does not split into as set correctly

Comment: @KidWithComputer Doesn't rule 3 only apply to 7-letter words...? I included "asset" specifically to test that.

Comment: Oh your so right! My mistake!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES10), 100 bytes

Returns an array of strings.

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.flatMap(s=>s[4]?[s.slice(0,q=s.length+!/^..([^aeiouy])\1../.test(s)>>1),s.slice(q)]:s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBDoIwEEWvUl21EQdJXJmAJ/AECKHgADUTCsxAIpfHunDzkv9@3tuulpvZjXIe/Av3Nt05zRh4JCeVqqAlKw876p/Nr8U9Dx@5BvUlmlIGwqGT/nSISwCdlxadXz6FeSYAMQiyaDZZlpjon02muLHZGz@wJwTynW71sXadqtGuOKt62TY3hOmIAgSV9BgsEcrRmP0L)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

Returns a string with additional spaces.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\S{5,}/g,s=>s.slice(0,q=s.length+!/^..([^aeiouy])\1../.test(s)>>1)+' '+s.slice(q))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBDoIwEIXhq6Ab2oBTWbiES7gUSQoOpWbSAlNIxHh2bEzcvOR9yf/Uq@ZutmM4Of/AvS93LiuGGUfSHQpVX9@X/KNM/mMmG/GcTyUDoTNhyA6qARC3RqP1y@su6wJAQUAOgmVVFTJLkzT7p5OUe@cde0Igb0Qvjq01SYt6xTlpl22zLl5LFCdgEgaMSoThGMsv)

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>200</del> 147 bytes

Port of [@Arnauld's Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263800/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY8xT8MwEIXFmp39lMkWraHAgIpSqSNDFyqmUpCTXNJDjpPaTkNb9VcwspQB_hP8GtyETix-eqfvvTu_f9lEKnm1_zk5paIqjYN2IGpHShTSJQvSubjHHF-DoIxfMHEwkaRhGwCkmEHhDZMmt0MYGyPXs6kzPjLnQ3jQ5CBqSYCVVGC9C2PKIUa5QgNxvdl49qCqVVLKPw7BLdBPlUIHjVReU4gNYupDVq7XlFooyFoqtQWvNYbtksqvdkozWylyY51OpKaqVtIhs5x7ZBcEf6f8I4bd4dFoisvjJyD6rF3Wv_l-exZtgoUQcpF5fiIr1kQjylgjLG1wdM23h-Jl1PmzQd_IJhSCzZ4kUlmv5_xxIEQojMhIp2Ol7jRreAvf-p2HHkUJsove8vyS947Wm15XyfkOlUVoYc670z52ne73nf4C)

Saved so many bytes thanks to the comments.

```scala
_.split(" ").flatMap(w=>if(w.size>4){val q=w.size+1-raw"..([^aeiouy])\1..".r.findAllIn(w).size;Seq(w.slice(0,q/2),w.slice(q/2,w.size))}else Seq(w))
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJdS8MwFAUf-ysufWpwBocIUlhhDwqCe1F8kKmQtmkXSdMuuZ1u0l_iy170R_lrTNOttOBLSE7Ouffcj68fkzDJLvb77xqzs6vfkydRVKVGcDitUUhaMExWQuX0nuf8w_PK-I0nCAsmFHx6ACnPoLCPgOnchDDXmm2XD6it5IWE8KgEwswxATZMgrEvPxY5xJxtuIa43u0sF2IhpT2QA664RaXk6DtVZWOhVIGppMC5ShdMiaqWDHlgCLGUxjv4-I8RQmfGerkTBo_Wek-GOlXgg08oli2HZla6YFXwXuoUZtGBCSAycBiVXOW4gmgGl6T_7erTbZtCcN1qS_V9SoPlK-OirLcv5HlKaYvpkWhtmW1wJ6aZUOmN0AZvlUtHqDDXRYXbYS4YWzmFKYEogmlPaIBLw0eKkfcRt7-19XeBjRQJD84nsCYTGCDryTCOG8AgXa_v8KabT-N1G3ZYtOPC_QE)

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s = "big beaver buzzing bill bite the bullet"
    println(splitAndManipulate(s))
  }

  def splitAndManipulate(s: String): List[String] = {
    s.split(" ").toList.flatMap(word => {
      if (word.length >= 5) {
        val regex: Regex = """..([^aeiouy])\1..""".r
        val q = if (regex.findFirstIn(word).isEmpty) {
          (word.length + 1) >> 1
        } else {
          word.length >> 1
        }
        List(word.slice(0, q), word.slice(q, word.length))
      } else List(word)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: [Try it online - 196 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY9NTsMwEIXFCimnGGVli2L-hISKUokFSCy6AbHiR3KaSTrIcVJ7QglRT8KmLOAkXAJOg5tSNmw8mufvzZt5_fATbfTR8ntrm8q6cgy9oBomo0rNkynZQl1hgc9RVKWPOGEYa7LQRQAZ5lCGRmhX-CGcOafb22t2wXIvh3BjiSHpSYAnbcCHLk6pgBT1EzpIm5eXwEJKxoSHEXiKQTUGGebahJpB6hCzAHvdtpR5KMl7qqyP-7F1CGNjha8N8ZnNxtpS3RjNKLyUAVlE0W_4P2K4XjUZXeNsszYk7w3nuydfnz4ZdV71LhFDLBVXgVN5cI51Lebhm3IxVwZtwdNRciy7VcwsCWocx0qJ2weNVDXtvbw7UGqlOZWTzS7Ieb60Yi4V-fOy5lZ2f4N2DuTe4ekCjcduo62E0xAeIG9ogmJ_MJODTTMbbDgpex_0qFzIxfqWt9-6XK7rDw) (both `>>1` to `/2`, and removed two spaces).

Comment: Also `>=5` can be `>4` for another -1 byte, and you can probably save some more bytes creating a variable for `w.length`, since you use it four times?

Comment: [Attempt this online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY8xT8MwEIXFmp39lMkWraHAgIpSqSNDFyqmUpCTXNJDjpPaTkNb9VcwspQB_hP8GtyETix-eqfvvTu_f9lEKnm1_zk5paIqjYN2IGpHShTSJQvSubjHHF-DoIxfMHEwkaRhGwCkmEHhDZMmt0MYGyPXs6kzPjLnQ3jQ5CBqSYCVVGC9C2PKIUa5QgNxvdl49qCqVVLKPw7BLdBPlUIHjVReU4gNYupDVq7XlFooyFoqtQWvNYbtksqvdkozWylyY51OpKaqVtIhs5x7ZBcEf6f8I4bd4dFoisvjJyD6rF3Wv_l-exZtgoUQcpF5fiIr1kQjylgjLG1wdM23h-Jl1PmzQd_IJhSCzZ4kUlmv5_xxIEQojMhIp2Ol7jRreAvf-p2HHkUJsove8vyS947Wm15XyfkOlUVoYc670z52ne73nf4C) 147 bytes.

Comment: -2 bytes: `_ split " "flatMap`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>261,265</strike> 232 bytes

gotta love the walrus. +4 bytes to fix rule 4.

```python
import re
def f(s,q=[]):
 for w in s.split():
  if len(w)<5:q+=[w]
  elif(k:=len(w))%2<1:q+=[w[:k//2],w[k//2:]]
  elif b:=re.search(r'(?=[^aeiou])([a-z])\1',w):q+=[w[:(i:=b.end()-1)],w[i:]]
  else:l=k//2+1;q+=[w[:l],w[l:]]
 return q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRasMwEET/c4olUCIRx8EphaJGFHwNVQWnWdVLVNleyTX15V27qX922JnHa39S3YTH55anib7ahhMwbq7owImYddpYqTbgGoYBKEDMY@spiaUEcuAxiEGen1S312awc4menLgpfV/kw@lc3EejbsfjyWaDWVLZFYaL0ox5xIo/asE78arNe4XU9FYKUx1GK9@KXTbIVSNI6UuO4SrkoZCLkFZbROX1ot8XL/@0XwD/BzCmngN0U8sUknBiW9InlFh9I0co@3GkMP/k/XwSQqpxbr3HtJVy@gU)

Comment: It looks like you have repeated logic in the last 3 cases where you do `q+=[w[:c],w[c:]]` for some value `c` you compute. You can probably shorten your code by computing `c` within the `if/elif/else` but doing the append afterwards.

Comment: [Whittled it down to 145 (and fixed rule 3 handling)](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv@YoltFhqg0KTHorAPfg3Egdka20Ly5KQNjHKz7vKoZeBeTMMEzJN3p1/Qtw2swQfCSLuNA4wsMTlDgYfYQXjIIkUrCH2gmAG1suazbK26NjK@e@3cppFFIuifmKxugnBLjeFxt9zy69fQoi36rDyUoNz2ZyPx9Pn/H7iXGaDVsN6kX1bpv9dL9stROOIfQxs35gRGlQPjAma@/NpXPHG2iKEQBMWai0SjNHgAzV0GRSsyhaoQfsRuoioMcLrQPILgvOkOouQqCRkMySVs9EJVEpIe2H9ipFxfkgY6urqKr79AQ)

Comment: *[144](https://tio.run/##NY1Bi8IwFITv/oqHLDRZNLKrhyXQPfRvaIXYvLbBNAkv0RD/fDce9jIw3wwzoaTZu@NPoHU1S/CUgHCjcYSRRS43MHqCDMZBFDFYk9gbghnZIFt2l61FxzLnvyflNCMUi0rDzKi5CsHOV4XGP0rPL19CiI9ml3mtwdHTnu3vh8M351wWg1ZDPsuhr8v/bpD9Gsi4xD5Htu3MBB2qJ1KE7vF6GVe9sbZKQkgzVmotJpjI4BM13AooyMpWqEH7CW6EqJHg/R/9guB8UjeLEFNNki0QVSlGR1AxYtoK6zMS43wXMbTNxTV8/QM)

Comment: actually I might just post this myself lol

Comment: go for it! thats awesome. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>142</s> <s>139</s> <s>134</s> <s>131</s> 130 bytes

```python
import re
for w in input().split():c=re.match(r'..([^aeiouy])\1...$',w)and 3or(w>w[:4])*len(w[::2]);c>0!=print(w[:c]);print(w[c:])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NasNADIX3PYUKhXhKO_Qni-KSXCR1YWwrsWA8YzRyzGTZZa_QjTftnXKbyqQFIek98cT39TNk6WKY5-9R9vcv5w_qh8gCjFf7yDABBa1hlMLYNHjSWTYbRts7abqCV9YWu3eHFMdcmbdHa-3N6m4yLrTwHLmYttOuXFfm1mModC2fKvPabB-uNwNTkMVq1PkXTVmZC8kf0Hz-rOkANbojcoJ6PJ0oqCbvtQmCdKiu9yhwYMIjtlBncDA5r6YKl5KngNBGjTFiiwwLXYo9Qojiao-QRC_iMySXM7VJf2kuXwYtiZRQLki_)

*-3 thanks to xnor one-lining it, with some comparison chaining on top to shave one byte off an `and`*

*-1 thanks to spooky_simon actually knowing how `re.match` works*

Basically just a bunch of incremental golfs to [spooky_simon's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263838/85334) (inspired by [xnor's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/263797/buzzing-bills-newspaper-four-letter-splits/263838#comment577248_263838), and with fixes to rule 3), but it's barely even recognizable anymore so I figured I may as well post it for myself.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NagMxDIX3PYUKgdglNf1blCnJRdIJeMZKxuCxXVkT42x7jG5m094pt6lDWhCS3qcHel8_sfAQ_Dx_T7y_fz1_2jEGYiC82QeCDNbXihMLqVJ0ts6mXxOqUXM_CFrulBLbnUYbptLK90el1GK5ylJ7A8-BRN7kbfPSyjuHXtS1eWrlW795uF1Hsp4vqK_kX_RNK69R_hLN54_OHqBDfURK0E2nk_VVW-dqYwQesFLnkOFAFo9ooCugIWtXoQETqpsQDRJcQqUwIvjAunMIieuFXYGkS7EmgU4J-fr5Fw)

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY49bsMwDIX3noKdYhWN0b8hcJFcJHUAyWJiArKkUHQMZeo9unhp75TbVEFagCD5Pj6A7-snZumDn-fvUfbL1eWThhhYgPFuHxgmIF8qjlKpOkVHZTbdmrEetHR9xYtdXVfbnUYKY27Vx3O9eJyU9hZeA1fTZto2b616cOirsjYvrXrvNk_368jk5Yq6Qv5F17TqluMvznw5GjqAQX1CTmDG85l80eRcaYIgPRbqHAocmPCEFkwGDZN2BVqwobgZ0SLDNVQKA4IPoo1DSFIu4jIknTPZBDollNvnXw) regex match starts at the beginning of the string so no need for end of line anchor

Comment: @spooky_simon Removing the end anchor splits `bassline` wrong (since the split is hardcoded at 3 instead of half the length), but removing the start anchor still works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch with bassline, totally missed it! heres another [-2 bytes for printing syntax](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BTsNADEX3nMJUSM1QGEFhgYLai6RBmiRuY2kyE804jaYr1lyBTTZwp94GR0GybP9vfet9__aJW--m6Wfg4-Pb9ZO63geGgDdHH2AEclL9wJnSsbckM693AXVnuG6zsNY6Kz4Mkh9SqQ7PWuu79cOojGvgxYds3I9F_lqqe4sukzXfluq93j_d7vpAjmerLjerg1ttxqLOS7Vw_ONM16-KTlChOWOIUA2XCznRZK00RuAWxbUWGU6B8IwNVAkMjMaKKcLEaMkhNF5iAbHBADNb9B2C82wqixBZLmwTRJMSNVF-SS4tg-ZEjMgL0h8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
S` 
(..(..(?=....)|([^aeiouy])(?=\3...)|.(.(?=...))?))(..+)
$1¶$+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/OEGBS0NPD4TsbfWAQLNGIzouMTUzv7QyVhMoFmMMFgSqgCjQ1LTX1AQq19bkUjE8tE1F@///pMx0haTUxLLUIoWk0qqqzDwgNzMnB0iUpCqUZKQCRXNyUksA) Link includes test case. Explanation:

```
S`
```

Split on spaces.

```
(..(..(?=....)|([^aeiouy])(?=\3...)|.(.(?=...))?))(..+)
$1¶$+
```

Split words of at least five letters in one of four ways:

- eight letter words are split after four letters
- seven letter words whose third letter is not a vowel and is doubled after three letters
- other seven letter words after four letters
- other words after three letters

`$+` just saves me counting to find the group number of the last capture group.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/), 379 bytes

I got kinda lazy at the end after banging my head against this problem for a couple hours. Since I wasn't sure if I could use built-in modules like `itertools` I decided not to test my luck and just make a function (which came out kinda bulky)

Here's my solution

```python
def f(l):
    if type(l) in [list,tuple]:
        for s in l:
            yield from f(s)
    else:yield l
b=lambda s:list(f([[w[p:p+(len(w)//2)]for p in range(0,len(w),len(w)//2)]if(len(w)>4 and len(w)%2==0)else(([(w[:a],w[a:])for a in[{1:4,**{1:a for a in[i+1 for i,(a,b)in enumerate(zip(w,w[1:]))if a==b and a not in"aeiouy"]}}[1]]])if len(w)==7 else w) for w in s.split()]))
```

Was I a bit smarter and managed to remove the function I could've saved about 100 bytes, but oh well...

Comment: you have like 20 bytes of white space in your function f, easy to shave it down for some freebies. Additionally, using https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107311/118465 can save maybe 10 bytes on the type checking...

Comment: thanks! those tips on type checking seem really useful. as for the whitespace in f, i coded this on my phone while i was having breakfast and i forgot i could do that... :')

Comment: the yield from is very very cool, never seen it before, so thanks as well!

Comment: "i coded this on my phone while i was having breakfast" -Legendary

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 46 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ ¿∧⁼Ｌι⁷›⁼§ι²§ι³№aeiouy§ι²⟦…ι³✂ι³⟧⪪ι⁻⁴⊘＆²⊕Ｌι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNS8RADIbv/orQUwbGSxU87GktogUFoUfxMJ1m20Cc1mmmuvvn6yxV0UACb56EfPjBRT86WdfDGAGbSVixDlPSRiOHHo2FAgpjgA@A@9Dh3XtyMuMjhV4H5Mxvst9Hckrxh@61Dh19IlsoM/0jr0zW1ZiCYuGIx3Qs/vHSnA2e83DFl@rohaphnLZWC42wp028mh2QzPRdu62eyROHNOO1hQcnC3V4y/rBM513Ly3UwUd6o6CZ/N6w2W5dW@6hJbdQhDadTvkB0LJIDkqgA@WsCOnFernIFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ
```

Split the input on spaces and loop over the words.

```
¿∧⁼Ｌι⁷›⁼§ι²§ι³№aeiouy§ι²
```

Check to see whether this is a seven-letter word with third and fourth letters both the same consonant.

```
⟦…ι³✂ι³⟧
```

If so then split it after three letters.

```
⪪ι⁻⁴⊘＆²⊕Ｌι
```

Otherwise split it after a number of letters given by a formula which results in splits of `3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4` for words of length `1` to `8`, which is the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-an`, 87 bytes

`-an` enables autosplitting on the implicit input, which is stored in `$F`.

The main strategy here is to abuse `String#slice!`, which removes the substring that matches the parameter from the original string and returns it, which means what remains can be returned as the second half. It can take as a parameter, among other things, a regex or a range, which means the 7-length case can be handled with a regex and everything else can be handled with a range.

```ruby
puts$F.map{|f|s=f.size
s>4?[f.slice!(s==7?/..(([^aeiouy])(?=\2)|..)/:0...s/2+s%2),f]:f}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZLBjtNADIYFxzyFWYHUCjZFFRJopdIbr8ChFMlJPMloJ-NqPEOUUp6Eyx5APBM8zXomRdpLJol_f_9vJz9_hdTMfw43t-hvjg-_UzS3H_5-PqUoLz_VI56-X8xFdqYWe6ZKPr7bH_Te2ZZerGS3e7_f1PVqdfiKZDnNx_Vqv_uyXV_qer25e1vXtWy2r-XVdv3GHO_MjwV_dXn49_xZk85n63torHNgBRAG2w9uBpJINFIHDeE3CtVAuRz1GDB0WoWJw31utV57BAYeCTocs3LCTJIYOKMLANB3y_vGEUQGZ02EkQOB4z6T0atmZk-AsRhlmGCnYTK_xUCKaXEs7aomJao5QgzY2xawbW1HPlYN5VyS2mGRcRg5CRjbJ7W75o08-WJzzXfCk14n9FGHVoMp2KhRwOgQUas96UAc5lwLupmxUfnT9VUDT5RJC1A3ogeMOYWM6Nx_j-uskw7IZSutPrHXMY2NYDgFcBRjFrKmR-131lOVsy4hUcT2XmDmlNPkQkS5BzYldRk-f42Wu7IrTlH_p6J7gi9UWX6FRw)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#εDg©4›i2ä®7Qi¬γθžPÃg2@iJ34S£]˜
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@dxWl/RDK00eNezKNDq85NA688DMQ2vObT634@i@gMPN6UYOmV7GJsGHFseenvP/f1JmukJSamJZapFCUmlVVWYekJuZkwMkSlIVSjJSgaI5OaklCuWJOUA6RSGpKDU1Bai4OLGyMjOlWCE3s7g4Mz@vWCEJCBKTkhUSi4tTSwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
#                      # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces
 ε                     # Map over each word:
  Dg                   #  Duplicate the current word, then pop and push its length
    ©                  #  Store this length in variable `®` (without popping)
    4›i                #  If the length is larger than 4:
       2ä              #   Split the string into two 'equal-sized' parts, where the
                       #   first part is one character longer for odd-sized strings
         ®7Qi          #   If length `®` equals 7:
             ¬         #    Push the first part with four characters (without popping
                       #    the pair)
              γ        #    Group adjacent similar characters together
               θ       #    Pop and keep the last character-group
                žPÃ    #    Only keep the consonants of this group
             g2@i      #    If the length of what remains is >=2:
                 J     #     Join the pair back together to the original word
                  34S£ #     And split it into parts of sizes [3,4] (instead of the
                       #     [4,3] done by the `2ä`)
 ]                     # Close all three if-statements and the map
  ˜                    # Flatten the list
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 99 bytes

```perl
$_=join$",map/(..([^aeiouy]))(\2...$)|(.{3,4})(.{3,4})|(...)(..)/i?($1||$4||$6,$3||$5||$7):$_,split
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYpLC8IwEITv/ooiOSRQt2h9gCBCbx48e/BRAgZdWdNgUkGtf924HhQRPMwMM984c6JBjKKcHCq0op0etcskgFxutMGqvqyVkqseAAjVSLjlaf@u3skDADdQGU6l6DaN6LOGqcg5BqyRGosy9Y4wxFjgLimMPptTUtTXK1quSMQWTBL2hlciE1r/fgtNzLc/nD5c22TmfW2@D3P0HivrH5ULr4wdR08)

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the word `missions`.

Comment: @Neil – good catch. Corrected.